# display people within a department

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, user-profile, user-profile-service

Is there anyway to display a list of people within a department which is pulled from the user profile service or similar? For example, our intranet has a site for each department and we'd like to have a nested unordered list in plain html (no silverlight) showing all the people in that department.

Answer (score 0):

Place a People Core Search Web Part on the page and use a fixed query of Department:HR or Department: Whatever you can change the look by changing the XSL.